# Cannot install capybara-webkit gem

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, capybara-webkit

This is really a tough one for me. I'm trying to migrate over to Mountain Lion but I get the following when trying to install capybara-webkit.

The initial error:

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
            /Users/martinb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
    cd src/ && /usr/bin/qmake /Users/martinb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capybara-webkit-0.14.1/src/webkit_server.pro -spec /usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -o Makefile.webkit_server
    cd src/ && make -f Makefile.webkit_server 
    g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o EnableLogging.o EnableLogging.cpp
    In file included from /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Headers/qnamespace.h:45,
                     from /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Headers/qobjectdefs.h:45,
                     from /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qobject.h:47,
                     from /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers/QObject:1,
                     from SocketCommand.h:4,
                     from EnableLogging.h:1,
                     from EnableLogging.cpp:1:
    /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Headers/qglobal.h:320:6: warning: #warning "This version of Mac OS X is unsupported"
    g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o Authenticate.o Authenticate.cpp
    In file included from /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Headers/qnamespace.h:45,
                     from /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Headers/qobjectdefs.h:45,
                     from /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qobject.h:47,
                     from /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers/QObject:1,
                     from SocketCommand.h:4,
                     from Authenticate.h:1,
[...]
    make[1]: *** [Authenticate.o] Error 1
    make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_default-ordered] Error 2


    Gem files will remain installed in /Users/martinb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capybara-webkit-0.14.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Users/martinb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capybara-webkit-0.14.1/./gem_make.out
```

So I installed the latest qt using homebrew:

```
> brew install qt
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/qt-4.8.2.mountainlion.bottle.1.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring qt-4.8.2.mountainlion.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Caveats
We agreed to the Qt opensource license for you.
If this is unacceptable you should uninstall.
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.2: 2752 files, 197M
```

Then:

```
> gem install capybara-webkit

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/martinb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby extconf.rb
cd src/ && /usr/bin/qmake /Users/martinb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capybara-webkit-0.14.1/src/webkit_server.pro -spec /usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -o Makefile.webkit_server
cd src/ && make -f Makefile.webkit_server 
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o EnableLogging.o EnableLogging.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o Authenticate.o Authenticate.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o SetConfirmAction.o SetConfirmAction.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o SetPromptAction.o SetPromptAction.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o SetPromptText.o SetPromptText.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o ClearPromptText.o ClearPromptText.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o JavascriptAlertMessages.o JavascriptAlertMessages.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o JavascriptConfirmMessages.o JavascriptConfirmMessages.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o JavascriptPromptMessages.o JavascriptPromptMessages.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o IgnoreSslErrors.o IgnoreSslErrors.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o ResizeWindow.o ResizeWindow.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o CurrentUrl.o CurrentUrl.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o ConsoleMessages.o ConsoleMessages.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:2:17: error: QtGui: No such file or directory
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:16: error: ‘QApplication’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:16: error: expected `;' before ‘app’
main.cpp:17: error: ‘app’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:8: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’
main.cpp:8: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’
make[1]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_default-ordered] Error 2
Command 'make' failed

make
cd src/ && make -f Makefile.webkit_server 
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtWebKit -I/usr/include -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:2:17: error: QtGui: No such file or directory
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:16: error: ‘QApplication’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:16: error: expected `;' before ‘app’
main.cpp:17: error: ‘app’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:8: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’
main.cpp:8: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’
make[1]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_default-ordered] Error 2


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/martinb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capybara-webkit-0.14.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/martinb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capybara-webkit-0.14.1/./gem_make.out
```

I'm really, really stuck. Is there a solution for this? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You might want to try removing every bit of the older Qt install. I just installed qt 4.8.4 (no previous install) from brew + capybara-webkit and had no errors.

Comment: Paul, thank you. To the best of my knowledge, the previous Qt was installed using macports. I removed all ports and macports itself. But in case there's an older version, what to look for and how to remove it? Thank you for any hints you can offer.

Comment: Based on your first error msg it looks like you may have an old QtCore here: /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework

Comment: I renamed the dir and now: http://pastie.org/6002106 UPDATE: Forgot to mention that I did that after renaming the dir: > brew uninstall qt > brew install qt

Answer (score 0):

Whoa! I followed Paul's advice (THANK YOU Paul!) plus linked qmake to the new version. (Was 4.7.3, I needed it to use the latest 4.8.2).

Hint: qmake -v to see which version is in use.

Had I only known this... :P