# Not able to install capybara-webkit using bundle install command in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am getting following error while executing command `bundle install` in my Rails 4 application.

```
> ruby -v
ruby 2.1.8p440 (2015-12-16 revision 53160) [i386-mingw32]

> rails --version
Could not find gem 'capybara-webkit x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

**My Gemfile**

```
...
.....
group :development, :localtesting, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.11'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  #gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
  gem 'i18n-tasks'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rspec_junit_formatter'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
end
.....
...
```

**Error**

```
Installing capybara-webkit 1.10.1 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby
        --with-gl-dir
        --without-gl-dir
        --with-gl-include
        --without-gl-include=${gl-dir}/include
        --with-gl-lib
        --without-gl-lib=${gl-dir}/lib
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
Command 'qmake ' not available

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.10.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/capybara-webkit-1.10.1/gem_make.out
Using guard-minitest 2.3.1
Using actionview 4.2.2
Using composite_primary_keys 8.1.2
Using friendly_id 5.1.0
Using paper_trail 4.0.2
An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (1.10.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.10.1'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

Note: I already tried to look into a post with similar problem [Cannot install capybara-webkit gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638051/cannot-install-capybara-webkit-gem) and tried to follow the solution by executing the following command. But got following error.

```
> qmake -v
'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Installation instructions are in the capybara-webkit wiki - https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit .  You'll want to install Qt 5.5.1 (5.6 is only supported if you build the QtWebKit module separately)

Comment: I've done that (OSX High Sierra) and the gem install still isn't working: "which qmake" => "/usr/local/opt/qt@5.5/bin/qmake" but installing the Gem gives me "Command 'qmake ' failed"

Comment: @sixty4bit That's not the error this question deals with which was `Command 'qmake ' not available` - so this really isn't the place to ask about it.  Open your own question with way more details than you've provided here.

Comment: if you get the error: `Error: qt@5.5: unknown version :mountain_lion` make sure you follow the Note in the documentation:  NOTE: If you get Error: qt@5.5: unknown version :mountain_lion, comment line #25 in Formula/qt@5.5.rb

Answer (score 13):

Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qt5-default libqt5webkit5-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04.1 This gives an error: `E: Package 'qt5-default' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 1):

`'qmake' is not recognized` likely means that Qt is not installed

```
brew update
cd $( brew --prefix )/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core
git checkout 9ba3d6ef8891e5c15dbdc9333f857b13711d4e97 Formula/qt@5.5.rb
brew install qt@5.5
echo 'export PATH="$(brew --prefix qt@5.5)/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Complete installation process is [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#ubuntu-trusty-1404)

Answer (score 0):

I have OS X El Capitan system.
I tracked on this link :

https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit

then

```
gem install capybara-webkit -- --with-opt-include=/usr/local/bin/qmake
```

This problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run:

```
QMAKE="$(brew --prefix qt@5.5)/bin/qmake" gem install capybara-webkit
```

in order to get the gem to install after I got Error: `qt@5.5: unknown version :mountain_lion` and followed the commenting step from the [Homebrew instructions](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#homebrew):

NOTE: If you get Error: qt@5.5: unknown version :mountain_lion, comment line #25 in Formula/qt@5.5.rb

Answer (score 0):

For [AltLinux](http://altlinux.org) it should be done the following:

1. As of root install *gem-capybara-webkit-devel* package:

   ```
   # apt-get install gem-capybara-webkit-devel
   ```
2. export the PATH's additionals required for the compilation:

   ```
   $ export PATH=/usr/share/qt5/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. install the gem with bundler

   ```
   $ bundle
   ```